# How many voice lines are in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Between all of the character voice commands and responses, how many individual voice lines/files are in TF2?

Comment: For future reference, why the down votes? What can be done to improve the question, or is this not the right site?

Comment: The question is kind of trivial, and has no visible impact on how you would play the game, or relates in any way to a problem you're trying to solve that would be considered on-topic here.  The biggest category of questions here are problem solving questions, where the asker is trying to find a solution to a problem they're having, usually in-game.  The second category, which this question belongs to, is fact-finding questions, but the good ones are related to game mechanics such that the asker has all the information they need in order to make an informed decision about how to play said game.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll try to ask more relevant questions then.

Comment: @Kurtoid Don't ask questions just for the sake of asking questions. Ask questions because you genuinely have an issue.

Comment: Why shouldn't informational questions like this be asked? If someone wants to know a fact about a game, isn't a game Q&A site the perfect place to ask it?

Comment: The other problem with this kind of question is that it's constantly changing when the game updates.  For example, the current accepted answer is missing all the new Merasmus lines from Halloween 2015, the new class lines for the new taunts, and the new Pauling lines for the Tough Break update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to GCFScape, as of 29-08-2015, `sound/vo` currently contains 26 folders and 11,347 files. This can be further broken down:

- `vo` itself has 4445 files, which are the main voices for the nine classes, the announcer, and the Eyelander.
- `vo/bot_worker` has 9 files, used for the robots in `rd_asteroid`.
- `vo/halloween_bombinomicon` has 62 files for the Bombinomicon on `plr_hightower_event`.
- `vo/halloween_boss` has 18 files for the Horseless Headless Horsemann.
- `vo/halloween_eyeball` has 20 files for Monoculus, which are all edited Demoman clips.
- `vo/halloween_mann_brothers` has 271 files for the Mann brothers of `plr_hightower_event`, who replace the typical announcer there.
- `vo/halloween_merasmus` has 703 files for Merasmus.
- `vo/items/wheatley_sapper` has 231 files for the Ap-Sap item.
- `vo/killstreak` has 22 files for the announcer relating to killstreaks, but I don't think they're used.
- `vo/mvm` has a total of 4041 files, which are all robotized duplicates of the classes' voice lines that existed at the time MvM was added to the game, used for the enemy robots in MvM.
- `vo/pauling` has 307 files for Miss Pauling relating to Gun Mettle contracts.
- `vo/taunts` has a total of 1218 files, where most of the nine classes' taunt-related lines are (though some are sound effects instead).